# How to access loop's variable on top?

Tags: java, jsp, variables, servlets, for-loop

I want to access loop's variable on the top, How to access it?

Let's say this example:

```
<title> your title name = <%=title%> </title>

<%
while(rs.next())
{
    String title = rs.getString("title")
} 
%>
```

I know, There is one approach that we could use `StringBuilder()` but not possible to call that variable on the top? Is it? It works from Top to bottom. But my approach is to get that(`title`) variable on the top. How to achieve it? Any idea?

Help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not well explained, i suggest another more accurate title like: 'In JSP how to use a variable defined in a previous scriplet block' or something similar. Because your question is about Jsp scriplets and not about loops.

Comment: Intead of accessing the `title` variable "on top" you may just move the `<title>` tag lower. Or use JavaScript to update the page title (`<script>document.title = <%=title%>;</script>`).

Comment: @TagirValeev Thanks  :)) man.. finally it did worked!

Comment: @Jhonny, oh... I thought I was joking. Posted an answer then :-)

Comment: Actually, the "business logic" (the loop reading data from DB query ResultSet in this case) should not be in JSP, but in a Controller. See [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern and e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page title at any part of your page via JavaScript:

```
<script>document.title = <%=title%>;</script>
```